# How to count for every day based on date ranges in ClickHouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Imagine I have this table:

| item | state | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | blue | 2022-12-27 |
| A | red | 2022-12-31 |
| B | green | 2022-12-28 |
| B | yellow | 2022-12-31 |
| C | blue | 2022-12-29 |
| D | red | 2022-12-26 |

The date column represents the date range of when the item existed. For example, "A" existed from 2022-12-27 to 2022-12-30 in the state "blue" and on the 2022-12-31 in the state "red".
Now, I want to have the count of the items per date if they are in the range.
The result table should look like this:

| date | count_item | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-26 | 1 | (D) |
| 2022-12-27 | 1 | (A) |
| 2022-12-28 | 2 | (A & B) |
| 2022-12-29 | 3 | (A & B & C) |
| 2022-12-30 | 2 | (A & B) |
| 2022-12-31 | 2 | (A & B) |

How can I achieve this in ClickHouse?

I tried to use this code, but it returns the wrong results.

```
SELECT
    toDate(date) AS d,
    COUNT(item) AS i
FROM my_table
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY d ASC WITH FILL STEP toIntervalDay(1)
INTERPOLATE ( i AS i );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH 
  MYTAB AS
(
  SELECT c1 as item, c2 as state, c3 as date
  FROM VALUES
  (
    ('A', 'blue',   toDate ('2022-12-27'))
  , ('A', 'red',    toDate ('2022-12-31'))
  , ('B', 'green',  toDate ('2022-12-28'))
  , ('B', 'yellow', toDate ('2022-12-31'))
  , ('C', 'blue',   toDate ('2022-12-29'))
  , ('D', 'red',    toDate ('2022-12-26'))
  )
)
, D AS
(
  SELECT toDate (arrayJoin (range (toUInt32 (min (date)), toUInt32 (max (date)) + 1))) AS dt
  FROM MYTAB 
)
, G AS 
(
  SELECT item, MIN (date) AS date_min, MAX (date) AS date_max
  FROM MYTAB
  GROUP BY item
)
SELECT 
  D.dt AS date
, count (1) AS count_item
, groupArray (G.item) AS comment
FROM D, G 
WHERE D.dt BETWEEN G.date_min AND G.date_max
GROUP BY D.dt
ORDER BY D.dt
FORMAT PrettyCompact
;
```

The result is:

```
+-------date-+-count_item-+-comment-------+
| 2022-12-26 |          1 | ['D']         |
| 2022-12-27 |          1 | ['A']         |
| 2022-12-28 |          2 | ['B','A']     |
| 2022-12-29 |          3 | ['B','C','A'] |
| 2022-12-30 |          2 | ['B','A']     |
| 2022-12-31 |          2 | ['B','A']     |
+------------+------------+---------------+
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/7a285fc8-92ca-4d72-bc76-f5233d10a421)

Answer (score 1):

Can try modifying my below code. It uses oracle syntax (a kind of pseudo) wherein I have generated dates using `dates CTE` and in the main query i am using another inner subquery to get aggregation results for the generated dates.

```
with tb as 
(
select 'A' as item, 'blue' as color, to_date('2022-12-27') as dt from dual
union all
select 'A', 'red' , to_date('2022-12-31') from dual
union all
select 'D', 'red' , to_date('2022-12-26') from dual
union all
select 'B', 'red' , to_date('2022-12-26') from dual
)
,new_dates as
(
Select t.mn + (level-1) as new_date
from
(Select min(trunc(dt)) mn,max(trunc(dt)) mx from tb ) t
connect by level-1<=(t.mx-t.mn)
),
t as 
(Select dt, listagg(item,',' )within group(order by item)
 ls,count(*) cnt from tb
 group by dt
 )
Select 
new_date, case when t.dt is null then 
             (select sum(t.cnt) from t where new_date<t.dt)
             else t.cnt end,
             case when t.dt is null then 
             (select listagg(t.ls,',' )within group(order by                      t.ls) from t where new_date<t.dt
             )
             else t.ls end
from new_dates n
left join 
(select * from t) t
on new_date=t.dt
order by new_date
;
```

[image]

Comment: I don' understand how I need to adjust it, so it works

Comment: check now ive added a running code.